# Removing frame handlers in Python

Tags: python, scripting

I am trying to script Blender for the first time following the documentation

```
import bpy


def my_handler(scene):
    print("Frame Change", scene.frame_current)

bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_pre.append(my_handler)
```

How can I replace a type of frame handler, respectively clear it, instead of appending to it every time I run the script? I can't directly write into the handler, since it is read only.
However closing and reopening the project can not be the answer either.

Comment: Thank you, I am still struggling with the documentation. That solved my problem.